! there is no package called 'XLConnectJars'
I'm knitting an older file in R Markdown. Why am I getting this when the compiler hits this chunk:
install.packages(
  'printr',
  repos = c('https://yihui.r-universe.dev', 'https://cran.rstudio.com')
)

! there is no package called 'XLConnectJars'
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  6. knitr:::process_group(group)
  7. knitr:::call_block(x)
  8. cache$library(params$cache.path, save = FALSE)
 11. base::library(p, character.only = TRUE)

I did not expect printr has anything to do with XLConnect. XLConnectJars is deprecaed too.

I also would not expect any connection between these packages. Are you sure there is no reference to XLConnectJars elsewhere in the code? Also: I would recommend against using install.packages inside of RMarkdown; it's better to have the required packages installed already.
